# c++ - Putting values (and solving for its sum) in an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have this code and its job is to ask the user if how many elements they would like to enter in the array - the user then enters their desired elements - *the elements are integers* -then the program solves for the sum of the entered numbers.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int arr[20], i, n, sum=0;

cout<<"How many elements you want to enter?: ";
cin>>n;
cout<<"Enter any "<<n<<" elements in Array: ";

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
cout<<"How many elements you want to enter?: ";
cin>>n;
cout<<"Enter any "<<n<<" elements in Array: ";
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
cin>>arr[i];
}

cout<<"Sum of all Elements are: ";

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
sum=sum+arr[i];
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   cout<<sum;
   getch();
}
```

I doesn't seem to work and the program doesn't run, so I can't put the actual output.

Expected output would be the sum of all the elements (integers) that the user entered.

Comment: Could you please be more specific what the problem is? Give an example input with the expected output, and the actual output. (Also, properly formatting your code would be nice).

Comment: why are you looping before asking for n? you only need to ask for n once, and shouldn't have loops around it

Comment: try printing out the elements after they're typed in. You're not using print statements enough.

Comment: you're also looping "n" times when you're printing the single sum. You don't need to loop that. Advice: comment out almost all of the stuff, get one thing working at a time, then add the next step. After each stage, temporarily output what has been entered.

Comment: maybe some output showing "you entered: x" after you enter each number. You can check that the feedback is correct as you go.

Comment: Helpful reading: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Maybe the problem is, I can't use **#include<conio.h>** as I use Linux

Comment: More problems lurking than that, but all conio gets you is getch. getch doesn't do you much good, just forces the program to pause for a key press after printing each value, so just remove it

Answer (score 0):

Basic advice: design as you go, and at each stage, use a print-out to tell you what values are entered.

```
cin >> n;

cout << "Please enter " << n << " values to sum: " << endl;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin >> arr[i];
    cout << "value #" << i << ": " << arr[i] << " entered." << endl;
}
```

You basically want to move on to the next stage of processing only when you're sure that your program works for entering the initial data. Take each stage of processing one at a time, and output what the current stage is. This makes it much easier to work out which stage of processing is causing an error. You can cut back on the print commands later on once it's working as intended, but I'd recommend leave then in there but commented out. Sometimes incorrect inputs cause errors again, and it's handy to re-enable the debug prints to tell you what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be an array? you can do it in a simpler way like this:

```
cout << "Enter number of elements\n"; 
cin >> n 

cout << "Please enter the elements \n"
int temp = 0; 
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<n ; i++){

   cin >> temp; 
   sum+=temp;
} 

cout << "Sum is: " << sum << endl;
```

One thin you need to note, you did not restrict the user to the max array size .. say he/she said 21 then you'll have an overflow which produces error.

Since you're using C++, I would suggest you go with vectors, or use the simple way I stated above.

Answer (score -1):

> Here is the program for your problem description.It takes input from the user to how much elements you want to enter into the array then it take elements and saved in an array then calculates the sum of array elements.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
  {
   int arr[20],i,n,sum=0;
   cout<<"How many elements you want to enter: ";
   cin>>n;
   cout<<"Enter any "<<n<<" elements in Array: ";
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
   cin>>arr[i];
   }
   cout<<"Sum of all Elements are: " << endl;

   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
    sum=sum+arr[i];
    cout << "sum of a[" << i << "] = " << sum << endl;
   }
  cout<< "the sum of all the elements (integers) that the user entered = " << sum;
  getch();
  return 0;
  }
```

Now this program gives the information sum of a[i] elements is and so on to the end of the loop.

Comment: What is the problem in my answer it runs fine and take input from the user and calculate the sum of array elements?

Comment: just replace cout <,< sum; to cout << "sum of all integers that the user enters = " << sum << endl;

Comment: Asker learned what from this answer? How to cut and paste? The jumbled code suggests they already know that. What they need to learn is how to assemble and debug a program.

Answer (score -2):

It is helpful to show the output or error message.

Try to convert cin into an integer or float for:

```
cin>>arr[i];
```